# How can I include a Javascript string constructor in a JSON string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm building a template to Jquery Mobile listviews. To make the template fully generic, I need to pass the listitem text. So currently my listview config looks like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-create="false" class="template" data-config='{
    "type":"listview",
    "data":"getRetailers",
    "custom_classes":["embedded_filter updateResults f-875","nMT pickList f-875 widget_listview","f-n",""],
    "lib":"static_listview.html",
    "tmp":"tmp_listview_inset",
    "lang":"locale_search",
    ...
    }'></ul>
```

My problem is how to include a Javascript constuctor for the list item text. This should be the following:

```
inv.company+', '+ inv.zip + ', ' + inv.city
```

But inserting it like this:

```
...
"text":"inv.company+', '+ inv.zip + ', ' + inv.city"
}
```

does not work.

**Question**:
How to include Javascript constructors in JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Not nice, but working:

1) In my JSON I'm only passing a function name like so:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-create="false" class="template" data-config='{  
    "type":"listview",
    "data":"getRetailers",
    "custom_classes":["embedded_filter updateResults f-875","nMT pickList f-875 widget_listview","f-n",""],
    "lib":"static_listview.html",
    "tmp":"tmp_listview_inset",
    "lang":"locale_search",
    "text":"buildRetailers",
    ...
}'></ul>
```

2) Then in my script I'm adding `buildRetailers` to my `dynoData` module:

```
var dynoData = {
    ...
    buildRetailers: function (inv) {
        return inv.company+', '+ inv.zip + ', '+ inv.city;
    },
    ...
}
```

3) And call this from my listview string builder:

```
....
listItem = listItem.replace( widget.options.re_theme, li_theme );
listItem = listItem.replace( widget.options.re_iconpos, li_iconpos );
listItem = listItem.replace( widget.options.re_icon, li_icon );
// call the function to return the list item text
listItem = listItem.replace( widget.options.re_text, dynoData[ li_text ](inv) );
```

So I can't seem to pass the function string in the JSON configuration so I need to add a function to construct what I need. If someone knows a better way please post. I will test and check.

Comment: only other way is write function in JSON double quoted text and use `eval` but `eval` is best to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
"text":"'"+ inv.company+ "', '"+ inv.zip + "','" + inv.city+ "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just pass what the object literal version of the inv object is.

```
"text" : {
    "company": "some value here",
    "zip": "another value here",
    "city": "another value"
}
```

Comment: nope, because `inv` contains about 30 fields and I'm having to loop over them to create the list of adresses. If it was a single item, then yes, I would probably do it like this.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you would do it like this:

```
"text": function(){ return inv.company+', '+ inv.zip + ', ' + inv.city }
```

But I'm not sure if it ever works. You can try it anyways.

Comment: There are no functions in JSON.

Comment: Oh then all the work I've done in JavaScript side works against the universe. It's a xmas miracle.

Comment: You might have object literals in mind. JSON was derived from their syntax, but they are not the same. You can see here that there is no syntax for functions in JSON: http://json.org/. No need to be snide.